# Django Static Files - No error but still doesnt load or change css

Tags: python, django, static-linking

It seems like this is an incredibly common issue and I've read the docs and tried all solutions and multiple youtube videos, but can't find a solution.

When I run the development server, my static files don't load but my terminal doesn't raise any errors either.

File layout:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVRiM.png)

SETTINGS.PY

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT:

```
July 15, 2020 - 21:02:47
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'mywebsite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[15/Jul/2020 21:02:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 148
[15/Jul/2020 21:02:51] "GET /staticfiles/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1672
[15/Jul/2020 21:02:51] "GET /staticfiles/images/headshot.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 1693
```

Comment: add a `print(STATICFILES)` in yout settings and check if the path is correct

Comment: also the variable name should be `STATICFILES_DIRS` [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to

```
STATICFILES = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
```

to this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
```

and make sure the name of the folder you have created for the static files is 'staticfiles'

Answer (score 0):

The correct configurations in `settings.py` for serving static files should be:

```
# For serving static files
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'

# All the staticfiles will be collected here
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

# This should be "STATICFILES_DIRS" and not "STATICFILES"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
```

The folder defined in [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) must be different from the `staticfiles` folder.
In the snippet given above, I have this folder named as "assets".

When you run `python manage.py collectstatic`, all the static files defined across the different apps will be "collected" here for deployment.

---

For serving media files:

```
# For media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

You also need to define [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) as per the documentation.

You can read more about managing static files [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)